# responsive file manager laravel dialog.php error

Tags: php, laravel, responsive-filemanager

i installed responsive file manager in my laravel project.
but i get this error

[Warning: scandir(../source/,../source/): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in C:\Users\M0RT3Z4\Desktop\MyBlog\public\panel\ckeditor\filemanager\dialog.php on line 648](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYf1d.png)

i want to upload my file in this directory:
public/filemanager/

and i changed 'upload_dir' in ckeditor/filemanager/config/config.php:

```
    'upload_dir' => getenv('APP_ROOT_PATH').'/public/filemanager/',
```

what should i do?

Comment: Did you edit in `../source/` somewhere? Or is that a default value of RFM?

Comment: @kerbholz
you mena currnet_path?
i did not edited
 'current_path' => '../source/',

Answer (score 0):

I think that the path is wrong, its necessary change config.php file in filemanager > config > config.php.

For example, you have "filemanager folder" inside public folder to store your images:

**upload_dir** => '/filemanager/' (public/filemanager) 
**current_path** => '../../../../filemanager/' (public/panel/ckeditor/filemanager/dialog.php)

To thumbnails, you can create a new folder inside filemanager

**'thumbs_upload_dir'**=>'/filemanager/thumbs/' (public/filemanager/thumbs) 
**'thumbs_base_path'** => '../../../../filemanager/thumbs'
(public/panel/ckeditor/filemanager/dialog.php)

*Remember that you are in file dialog.php*